# Need ideas to transform F# imperative code to functional

Tags: f#, functional-programming, imperative

I have a function witch is written in an imperative style and cant get my head around on how to convert it to a more robust functional approach.

The function takes a seq of strings and returns a seq of tuples where each tuple consists of the 2,7,12,.. and 5,10,15,.. item from the input.

Example:

Input = { "Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "set", "amet", "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "Aenean", "commodo", "ligula", "eget", "dolor", "Aenean", "massa" }

Ouput = { ("ipsum", "amet"), ("adipiscing", "commodo"), ("eget", "massa") }

```ml
let convert (input : seq<string>) : seq<(string * string)> =
    let enum = input.GetEnumerator()
    let index = ref 0
    let first = ref ""
    let second = ref ""

    seq {
        while enum.MoveNext() do
            let modIndex = !index % 5
            index := !index + 1

            if (modIndex % 2 = 0 && !first = "") then first := enum.Current
            if (modIndex % 5 = 0 && !second = "") then second := enum.Current

            if modIndex = 0  then
                let result = (!first, !second)
                first := ""
                second := ""
                yield result
    }
```

Any help or tip for a starting point is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not completely understand the behaviour you want - what is the algorithm for generating indices that you want to pair? Anyway, one nice functional solution is to take the elements you want to pair separately and then combine them using `Seq.zip`.

You can use `Seq.mapi` to add indices to the values and then use `Seq.choose` to get the values with the right index (and skip all other values). For hardcoded indices, you can write something like:

```
let indexed = input |> Seq.mapi (fun i s -> i, s)
Seq.zip 
  (indexed |> Seq.choose (fun (i, v) -> if i=1 || i=6 || i=11 then Some v else None))
  (indexed |> Seq.choose (fun (i, v) -> if i=4 || i=9 || i=14 then Some v else None))
```

I used your numbers -1 because the indices are from 0 - so the above gives you the results you wanted. The second series looks like multiples of 5, so perhaps you wanted `i%5 = 4` to generate second elements:

```
let indexed = input |> Seq.mapi (fun i s -> i, s)
Seq.zip 
  (indexed |> Seq.choose (fun (i, v) -> if i=1 || i=6 || i=11 then Some v else None))
  (indexed |> Seq.choose (fun (i, v) -> if i%5 = 4 then Some v else None))
```

I still don't see the general mechanism for generating the first elements though!

**EDIT** One more idea - is the first sequence generated by `i*5 + 2` and the second by `i*5`? In that case, your example is wrong, but you could write it like this:

```
let indexed = input |> Seq.mapi (fun i s -> i, s)
Seq.zip 
  (indexed |> Seq.choose (fun (i, v) -> if i%5 = 2 then Some v else None))
  (indexed |> Seq.choose (fun (i, v) -> if i%5 = 0 then Some v else None))
```

... or if you want to make the code shroter, you can refactor:

```
let filterNthElements div rem = 
  input |> Seq.mapi (fun i s -> i, s)
        |> Seq.choose (fun (i, v) -> if i%div = rem then Some v else None)

Seq.zip (filterNthElements 5 2) (filterNthElements 5 0)
```

Comment: I had to add a to change it to (fun i s -> i + 1, s) and it works. I really like the functional style more.

Thanks for your Help, your Blog and the hard work you put into answering SO questions!

Answer (score 1):

Here's more idiomatic way to do that. Actually, it's one-liner; I've just aligned it for better readability.

```
let Input = [ "Lorem"; "ipsum"; "dolor"; "set"; "amet"; "consectetuer";
              "adipiscing"; "elit"; "Aenean"; "commodo"; "ligula"; "eget";
              "dolor"; "Aenean"; "massa" ]

// Short solution that does not support more than two values
let Output1 =
    Input
    |> List.fold
        (fun (i, l1, l2) x ->
            if i=4 then 0, None, (l1.Value, x)::l2
            elif i=1 then i+1, Some x, l2
            else i+1, l1, l2
        )
        (0, None, [])
    |> fun (_, _, elem) -> elem
    |> List.rev
```

#### Idea

The general idea is based on three steps:

1. Splitting the list into a `List` of *tuples*, taking 2nd and 5th strings. **WARNING** If the original data length is not a multiplier of 5, the trailing element will be lost.
2. Filtering out temporary data from a *triple* by taking the third element, which is our primary goal;
3. Reversing the list.

---

#### Explanation

The first line is the hardest one.

Let's define our *state*. It will be a *triple* of sequential number, an `string option` that contains strings ##2, 7, etc and an "outer" `(string*string) list` that is added once we meet elements ##5, 10, etc.

The function will place the 2nd, 7th, etc elements to the "inner" `string option`, or, if `i` equals to 5, 10, etc., form a *tuple* and add it to the "outer" `List` (dropping the inner value for sake of clarity).

We use `List.fold`, and therefore the final list is to be reversed.

An initial state is a *triple* of `(0, None, []). More info on`List.fold` in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353894).

The second line just takes the third element from a *triple*. I've made it a function to allow chain binding.

The third line reverses the `List` due to the nature of `::` operator.

As per length of the initial list. If it has found the "2nd" element but did not reach the "5th", the second element of a *triple* has the value. You may detect the erroneous situation by verifying it:

```
...
|> fun (_, temp, elem) ->
    if temp.IsSome
    then failwith "Data length must be a multiplier of 5"
    else elem
...
```

---

Here's a bit longer code that supports more than two elements:

```
let Output2 = 
    Input
    |> List.foldBack
        (fun x (i, l1, l2) ->
            if i = 4
            then 0, [], (x::l1)::l2
            else i+1, x::l1, l2
        )
        <| (0, [], [])
    |> fun (_, _, elem) -> elem
    |> List.choose
        (function
        | [_; first; _; _; second] -> Some (first, second)
        | _-> None
        )
```

Note this variant does not drop elements during the first call, so you may retrieve more than two items.

**IMPORTANT**: The list is processed in the reverse order, and so the item index is calculated from the end of input. You may change it to `List.fold` in cost or further reversing the list as in `Output1`.

Mind the reverse binding operator `<|` due to signature of `List.foldBack`.

You may check for errors in a similar way: by testing if the "inner" list is not empty.

Comment: I like your solution as well because you are not limited to the Zip or Zip3 function and can simply add more elements to the result tuple. The problem here is that foldBack does not exist for sequences.

Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Oh, I have just updated my answer for a shorter solution which does not support multiple values. Let me roll it back to keep both.

Answer (score 0):

I come from haskell not f# so i will give a probably non valid f# code idea:

At first I would generate two lists from my input:

```
let zeromod5 = filter (index == 0 % 5) input
let twomod5 = filter (index == 2 % 5) input
```

which should result in the lists

```
{ "ipsum", "adipiscing","eget"}
{ "amet", "commodo","massa" }
```

and then zip them, i. e. make a list of pairs by something like

```
zip zeromod5 twomod5
```

### Edit:

Haskell version:

```hs
zipWeird :: [String] -> [(String, String)]
zipWeird ss = zip twoMod5s zeroMod5s
            where zeroMod5s = map fst $ filter (\(_,y) -> y `mod` 5 == 0) eSS
                  twoMod5s = map fst $ filter (\(_,y) -> y `mod` 5 == 2) eSS
                  eSS = zip ss [1..]

zipWeird2 :: [String] -> [(String, String)]
zipWeird2 ss = map fst $ filter (\(_,y) -> y `mod`5 ==1) ezSS
             where zSS = zip (tail ss) (drop 4 ss)
                   ezSS = zip zSS [1..]

input :: [String]
input = words ("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, "++
              "sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore "++
              "magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et "++
              "accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd "++
              "gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit "++
              "amet.")

main :: IO ()
main = do 
          print $ zipWeird input
          print $ zipWeird2 input
```

Comment: As you said, that's not valid F# (in fact, it's not valid Haskell either). If you're on Mac or Windows, then you can easily learn F# using http://www.tryfsharp.org which hosts the F# compiler in the browser. If you're on Linux, then there is a site that runs F# on server-side - it does not have that nice UI, but you can still use it to run basic F#: http://tryfs.net/